Knns and embedding based results
I recently tried to identify merchant similarity basis some attributes using KNNs and Word2 vec embeddings. Merchant attributes were embedded using Word2vec.
However, when i run a KNN model on these, my model is giving some weird results. eg if merchant 1 has attributes, like transportation, rental, online..the 10 KNN based merchants are those which do not belong to these attributes even though there are merchants with some common attributes.
Why is this happening?
i tried normalizing the embeddings. I considered concat/centroid/sum of the embeddings of the attribute.
I expected KNN to give me merchants which either have all the same attibutes or some common attributes. The results are such that the attributes are not common at all

Your description is insufficient to guess what your full data is like, how your word2vec-based features were calculated or combined, and what data the KNN step is applied against. So, any number of things could be wrong in approach or implementation. Can you expand your question with more detail, and at least excerpts of code/pseudocode, and example data/results, to clarify? (If your 'attributes' are just keywords, and you have a small number, and you just want "similarity" to be other merchants sharing some attributes, there are much simpler approaches & word2vec features may be overkill.)

my data has 4 columns: merchant name, and attributes that describe them. These attributes are 3. Eg: Merchant Name: Zepto, Attribute1: food delivery, Attribute 2: Online, Attribute 3: Grocery. I embedded A1, A2,A3 using word2vec and then concatenated the 3. I did this on the overall datasets. Then i used KNNs(cosine distance) to determine the nearest merchants to a given merchant

How many total merchants and how many total unique attributes? Did you train your own word2vec model? Is it possible that 'Grocery' could be in one merchant's 'Attribute1' column but another's 'Attribute3' column, but you still want it to mean the same thing? (If so, concatenating 3 vectors won't achieve the desired effect.) Did you try any simpler techniques first?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
